# How to make my png image to glowing gif image?

Tags: image, image-processing, photoshop

[image]This is my blue color image ,like this i want red color ,how to change red color image to glowing effect.,I Want image with glowing effect,can anybody help me how to do it.
This is image url ,for this image i need some glowing effect (image in gif format),how can i do it.

[image]

This is my image.
Your help will be appreciated

Comment: If you're not coding this pragmatically, then this belongs on [superuser](http://superuser.com/). If you are, then please include code so far (even the coding language would be useful at this stage) :(

Comment: @jbutler483,not programmingly,normal image like blue color,what i have added in my question.

Comment: Then please post this question on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/), where it will be on-topic. Cheers

Comment: SuperUser telling ,to post image you need 10 reputations.what shoul d i do?

Comment: Right click on your image here and choose 'Copy Image URL' - another user may add it for you after following the link

Comment: could you link me to the superuser Q? as I would like to add my input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are really needing to do is create an animated GIF. If you have Photoshop, you can do this via these methods:

**Method 1** - use existing blue graphic

1. Open blue CS3ZS.gif image in Photoshop
2. In the Layers panel, add an Adjustment layer above all other layers (select top layer, then in Adjustments panel select Hue icon)
3. Change the Hue to +160 (or whatever you like)
4. File > Save for web > select GIF

[image: changed blue to red]

**Method 2** - add glow animation to your red graphic

1. Open red TDnmm.jpg image in Photoshop
2. Layers panel > right-click Background layer > Layer from background
3. Select black background on stage and delete it - this will give you a transparent background
4. Then create another layer with the new "glow" effect
5. In the Timeline window use the frame-base animation mode
6. Create one frame with the glow layer visible and one frame with it hidden and a third frame with the glow visible again
7. Now select the first two frames and from the animation options panel, select "tween frames" and use 3 frames. Do the same for frames 2 & 3.
8. Select animation duration as Forever
9. Save for Web as a GIF

[image: JPG to GIF red glow]